# In Jekyll, how do I render custom metadata for a collection?

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I have the following in my `_config.yml` file:

```
collections:
  nr_qa:
    output: true
    permalink: /:collection/:name
    title: 'Node-RED Questions and Answers'
    descriptions: 'Node-RED is a flow-based (visual) programming tool. These pages have some information that may be currently missing from the documentaiton.'
  github_pages:
    title: 'GitHub Pages and Jekyll/Liquid'
    description: 'Hints and tips on using Jekyll for publishing to GitHub Pages.'
    output: true
    permalink: /:collection/:name
```

and I want to create an automatic index for my collections. So I use code like this:

```
## {{ site.collections.github_pages.title }}

{{ site.collections.github_pages.description }}

<ul>
{% for item in site.github_pages %}
  <li>
    <a href="{{ item.url }}">{{ item.title | replace:'_',' ' }}</a>
    <p>{% if item.description %}
        {{ item.description }}
    {% else %}
        {{ item.excerpt | strip_html }}
    {% endif %}</p>
  </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

And yes, I know I've rather mixed up my markdown and html there. Not relevant to this question.

The problem is that `{{ site.collections.github_pages.title }}` and `{{ site.collections.github_pages.description }}` don't render anything even though I think they should.

Can anyone point out my mistake please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `title` and `description` should be included in each collection, and not in `_config.yml`.

Check out [Accessing Collection AttributesPermalink](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/collections/#accessing-collection-attributes) for further details.

## update

`title` can be present in each collection metadata in `_config.yml`. The problem is how you are accessing those variables.

One approach is to have a specific layout for each collection, then you can access them like:

```
{% assign col = site.collections | where: 'label','github_pages' | first%}.
TITLE: {{ col.title }}.

DESCRIPTION: {{ col.description }}.
```

Comment: This seems to be a failing in the documentation then since https://jekyllrb.com/docs/collections/#step1 and some previous issues/PRs imply that you should indeed be able to do this. Annoying to have to create yet another file. Many thanks for your response.

Comment: I've raised a new Jekyll Issue [#6661](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/6661) for this as it is now clear that collection documents don't render metadata soon enough to allow the frontmatter variables to be used in the document itself.

Comment: Something is not clear, why do you assume that that is the expected behaviour? I've never seen such metadata in config. In code it also says `Only available to actual Pages and NOT TO COLLECTION DOCUMENTS` when it define titles and descriptions.

Comment: It is implied in the documentation on collections. Where it says that you can put such metadata into the config file - why say you can put it there if you can't then access it?

Comment: I've actually updated my issue now since it became obvious that my first test page was not behaving as other test pages I set up afterwards. Still not sure why that is but it is still happening with the original test page but not with the other test pages I created. Anyway, you still can't access the metadata defined in the config file so I'm guessing at the moment that the docs need updating?

Comment: Thanks! That got me to a working solution - shown [here](https://totallyinformation.github.io/github_pages/test2). Open the dev console and you can see all of the page and collection metadata. That leaves me with the non-working page issue referenced above, possibly github page related, not related to this q - creating a page in a collection directly in the GitHub web app doesn't seem to correctly add to the collection for some reason. But many thanks for the help & the correct answer.

Comment: Correction, solution is here: https://totallyinformation.github.io/github-pages/test2